# Site layout breaks on mobile view

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport

I've been writing a layout framework for building my own sites and everything has been going fantastic until a hit a slight bug today.
Everything was fitting to the screen except one item that just wouldn't fix itself. I realised the issue there was that I forgot to add the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Once this was added the first issue fixed itself but another has arose. As you can see by the screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

Ignoring my ugly mug, the issue is the white space that appears on the right hand side of the screen. It seems as if something has set the width to NOT be the device's actual width.
Before adding the viewport meta tag that white space wasn't there but without the tag I have a few other issues.

The media queries i've been using are:

```
@media (min-width 768px)
@media (min-width 992px)
@media (min-width 1200px)
```

All other code can be found [Github](https://github.com/Leaderproxima/Stronghold-Framework/blob/master/src/stylus/_grid.styl)

EDIT: Here is a live version of the site [Proxi-corp](http://proxi-corp.co.uk)

Comment: Have you tried adding `position: relative; width: 100%` to the style of your `body`?

Comment: The horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the left screenshot suggests the issue may be present there too. It might be an element further down the page with a fixed/minimum width. Are you able to provide a hosted copy of the page for us to inspect?

Comment: @cfreear I've added a link in the EDIT

Comment: Your banner-items div has a width of 96%. This plus the `left: 50px` will always make it larger than your viewport apart from on larger screens.

Comment: In other words the `max-width` bit is calculated first then `left` pushes it over 50px, not the other way round which is probably what you were expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove/rethink `.banner-items{ left:50px;}`

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. I realised that mistake as soon as cfreear said about the scrollbar. Removed and everything is working fine eventhough my .banner-items aren't in the exact right place anymore.

Comment: Also, take care when you use width/max-width in percetanges and margins in pixels. This may cause layout breaks too

Answer (score 1):

Remove this rule

```
.banner-items {
    /* left: 50px; */
}
```